# Can I write the following Django code more effectively?

Tags: django, loops, templates, object, nested

I have a couple of models - `User` & `Score`. I am displaying data from those models to my template. Data from `Score` is filtered based on data from `User`. I am using nested for loops and an if condition within the template to get my desired result. However, I want to know if there is a better way of coming up with the same result because once the data gets huge by number, the nested for loop is going to use up a lot of time and resource.

**models.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Score(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
def Home(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    scores = Score.objects.all()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'users': users, 'scores': scores})
```

**home.html (template)**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for score in scores %}
    {% if score.user == user %} {{ user }} -- {{ score.subject }} -- {{ score.score }} <br>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Result**

```
Michel -- Physics -- 80 
Michel -- Chemistry -- 90 
Zarif -- Physics -- 100 
Zarif -- Biology -- 80
```

This question is a simplified version of [this](http://tinyw.in/HQTV). If you can, maybe answer over there too!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've posted the same question in Code Review but it still has 1 view on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following way you do not need to query for all the scores as well nor do you need to compare the objects. But I am sure the problem you are trying to solve is different :).

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% for score in user.score_set.all %}
    {{ user }} -- {{ score.subject }} -- {{ score.score }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If I follow your code then the user -- subject -- score will be displayed even if there is no foreignkey relation to that subject with the user. I used the if statement to check whether the score.user is equal to the user object currently in memory. Otherwise, ALL SUBJECTS will be printed for EACH USER and that's not what I'm going for. There is a method called zip(), I've read it somewhere, but failed to understand what it does. Is that related to my problem?

Comment: Only the user subject and score are pulled there. Only the ones with fk relations are used here.

Comment: Sorry, this code doesn't show anything in my html. Just gave it a try. :( Should it be user.scores_set.all?

Comment: yup. edited the response as well. thx

Comment: `score_set` to be precise. Not `scores`. Thanks for this.

Comment: can u please follow the link at the bottom of my question and see if you can figure out what I should do over there. Kinda the same problem, but it's more complicated. Over here we are hoping one model with score_set, there's like three models to hop over there.

Comment: nvm buddy. solved it.